# Why doesn't Session.Remove remove the session object if followed by a thrown exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I have the following sample code that reproduces my issue:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var test = Session["test"] as string;
    if (test == null)
    {
        Session["test"] = "test";
        Response.Redirect(Request.Path, false);
    } 
    else
    {
        Session.Remove("test");
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Essentially I want to be able to remove the object from the session regardless if an exception is thrown or not. The above code block will run fine the first page load, but once the redirect occurs it will continue to throw an exception for every subsequent page load. The object never actually gets removed from the session.

If you place a watch on the throw you will see that the session object has been removed.

**Edit #1:** After a bit more testing I have noticed that this behavior is only present in the StateServer state mode. I have tested against InProc and it appears to work as expected. I am not able to test against the SQL Server mode.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you are treating the lack of the value in `Session` the same as if it is blank (or whitespace).

I would recommend the following code instead:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Does the value exist in Session?
    if(null != Session["test"])
    {
        // No, so throw an exception
        throw new Exception();
    }

    // Grab the value from Session and cast it to a string
    var test = Session["test"] as string;

    // Is the string null or blank?
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(test))
    { 
        // Yes, so give it a value of 'test' and redirect to another page
        Session["test"] = "test";
        Response.Redirect(Request.Path, false);
    } 
    else
    {
        // The value was not null or blank so rip it out of Session
        Session.Remove("test");    
    }
}
```

Comment: Karl, I think my example may have been slightly confusing. It isn't my intention to throw an exception if the session object doesn't exist. My intention was to show that an unhandled (forced in my example) exception prevents the session object from being removed. I have also fixed the condition to check for null rather than an empty string.